# undef singleton method from ruby object

Tags: ruby

I would like to be able to undef a singleton method on a given object.

```
class A
end

a = A.new
def a.foo
  puts "bar"
end

# undef a.foo here
a.foo # should crash
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class A
end

a = A.new
def a.foo
  puts "bar"
end

a.instance_eval { undef :foo }

a.foo # =>  undefined method `foo' for #<A:0x8469c60> (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: Oh nice! Much better syntax!

Answer (score 12):

```
class << a
  undef foo
end
```

Alternatively:

```
a.singleton_class.send :undef_method, :foo
```

Comment: Haha.. You were faster than me.. I just figured it out :-) -- also, thanks for the alternative solution! (I will accept the answer as soon as SO allows me to)